# Using the chain rule to derive a result about a homogeneous differentiable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am asked to show the result specified below using the chain rule but I am struggling to understand how we apply the chain rule to this function. I am fine with applying the chain rule when we have a function of the form $g(t)=f(x_1(t),x_2(t),...,x_n(t))$ but with regards to the question below, why when we apply the chain rule do we get a term of the form $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}$, when we are letting lambda vary and not $x_k$?

[image]

Comment: This is precisely the type of chain rule application you say you're fine with. $t=\lambda$! The notation would perhaps be better if you used $x_k=\lambda u_k$ rather than using $x_k$ in both places.

Comment: Where would I use your substation in the above? I think this is where my confusion is come from since I thought we would have to do ${\partial (λx_k)}$ instead of ${\partial x_k}$

Comment: No, that's horrible notation. You're taking partial derivatives with respect to the $k$th variable.

Comment: You'd end up with $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda x_i}\frac{\partial \lambda x_i}{\partial \lambda}$

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay if I let $y_k=λx_k$ then we would have $f(y_1,y_2,...,y_k)$ so if I take the λ derivative we get $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_k}x_k$ but this isn't the same as what we want

Comment: You'll sub $\lambda =1$ in the last step, so this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Define $g(\lambda)=f(\lambda x_1,\lambda x_2,\cdots,\lambda x_n)-\lambda^Df(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$. Note that this function $g(\lambda)=0$, and that $g'(\lambda)=0$. Apply Chain Rule on both sides of $g(\lambda)=0$ and see what will happen!

**EDIT:** $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial \lambda}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda x_k}\frac{\partial \lambda x_k}{\partial \lambda}-D\lambda^{D-1}f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)\\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial \lambda}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda x_k}x_k-D\lambda^{D-1}f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$$
To see this easily, you may do the following:

Let $f(\lambda x_1,\lambda x_2,\cdots,\lambda x_n)=f(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n)$. For 
 every $i$, $y_i=h(\lambda)$. Then you kind of have a relationship between them: $\lambda\rightarrow y\rightarrow f(\cdot)$.

Comment: I am unsure of how to apply the chain rule to the first term since I have seen in answers that we are seeing how f varies with each $x_k$ and then multiply this by how (λx_k) varies with λ, but I get from the chain rule we should see how f varies with λx_k but this appears to be incorrect

Comment: I added some words, see if they tackle your confusion.

Comment: Therefore, you do not have "how $f$ varies with each $x_k$" in the first place. This is obtained by substituting $\lambda=1$ at the final step.

Comment: yes I am more than happy with the formula you have expressed and it fits in with my understanding of the chain rule, so why does the desired formula have ${\partial x_k}$ instead of what you have above. Is it just signifying the kth variable of f but it is unclear as it has used x again?

Comment: If you let $\lambda = 1$, then you'll have the desired formula. The question didn't write in a more compact way, but I think it is correct.